# Blazor Webassembly error when adding a ASP.NET Core Web API Project Reference

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, blazor-webassembly

I created two fresh new projects a Blazor Web Assembly without checking the option of *ASP.NET Core hosted* because I did not want to create the other two projects that get created. Followed by a fresh new ASP.NET Core Web API project. After creating this project and writing any code, I added a few nuget packages to my web api project that I plan on using. I then expanded the Blazor Web Assembly project and right clicked on Dependencies, clicked on Add Project Reference and selected my Web API project. Then when building both projects, the web api passes and the blazor web assembly fails because of `Error NETSDK1082`. The exact error is shown below.

> C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.FrameworkReferenceResolution.targets(391,5): error NETSDK1082: There was no runtime pack for Microsoft.AspNetCore.App available for the specified RuntimeIdentifier 'browser-wasm'.

I looked up online for that error and attempted the solution where I add two lines of code into my .csproj file inbetween the `<PropertyGroup>` section, but even after adding this it failed. I even deleted the obj folder and rebuilt the blazor project but it produced the same error.

```
<RuntimeIdentifier>browser-wasm</RuntimeIdentifier>
<UseBlazorWebAssembly>true</UseBlazorWebAssembly>
```

`Blazor Web Assembly Project`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly" Version="5.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer" Version="5.0.10" PrivateAssets="all" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Net.Http.Json" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\PolkWebAPI\PolkWebAPI.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

`ASP.NET Core Web API Project`:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net5.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="5.0.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="5.0.10">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
    <PackageReference Include="Swashbuckle.AspNetCore" Version="6.2.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**I have not added any code to any of the projects I just installed a few nuget packages to the web api project and added the project reference to the blazor web assembly which produced the error.**

**Following up to request**:

in the `project.assets.json` file I see two other sections that include `browser-wasm`:

```
 "downloadDependencies": [
      {
        "name": "Microsoft.NETCore.App.Runtime.browser-wasm",
        "version": "[5.0.4, 5.0.4]"
      }
    ],
    "frameworkReferences": {
      "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
        "privateAssets": "all"
      }
    },
    "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"
  }
},
"runtimes": {
  "browser-wasm": {
    "#import": []
  }
}
```

Which section are you talking about to uninstall each nuget package manually ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update:
It seems you were trying to add a reference to the Web API to the blazor web assembly (WA) project. You do not need to do that. There are two WA models:

1. .net core hosted: You can create this type of project by ticking the ".net core" hosted when creating your WA project. It creates three projects by default. Client, server (mostly API controllers) and shared. Client and server both refer to the shared project. The shared project has all the classes that both WA application and controllers in server.
2. Standalone: In this case, you get two projects. Note that you can add another shared project like in (1) above to use classes that both can use. However, in this case the API controller need not even know it is talking to a blazor app.

You see the 'browser-wasm' error because of nuget packages that are incompatible with blazor wasm. You got the error because you added the server project reference to the WA project.

Read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/hosting-models?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

If cleanly opting for (1) or (2) does not work, search for `project.assets.json` in your project folder and search the section with browser-wasm. Check the list of packages in that section and try uninstalling those nuget packages one by one.

https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/36711

Comment: I see, I guess even the standard web api nuget packages that came pre-installed are incompatible because I just created the same two projects but this time without adding any nuget packages and just adding the web api project as a project reference in the blazor web assembly. But I found the `project.assets.json` file and searched for `browser-asm` I see a section named `net5.0/browser-wasm` which begins on line 1797 to 3600. Is it that super long section I have to uninstall all those nuget packages one by one?

Comment: I also see two sections that show the following in the original post. Please check that out as well.

Comment: You seem to have two different targets (.net5 and .net6). Can you do a clean start in either one of them and see if it works?

Comment: I just created a brand new blazor web assembly and made sure the target framework is .NET 5.0 (Current) and only selecting Configure for HTTPS. Then under the same solution, I added a ASP.NET Core Web API with Target Framework of .NET 5.0 (Current), Selected Configure for HTTPS and clicked on Enable OpenAPI support. I then build them individually and ran them individually. The blazor wa was ran on IIS express which worked. I then ran the web api as IIS Express and that worked as well.

Comment: This time, I did not add any nuget packages either for these sets of projects. After running them individually on the blazor wa I right clicked -> add -> project reference -> selected WebApi. Then right clicked on the solution (2 projects) -> set startup projects -> made sure "Start" was selected for both projects. Hit the play button but I get the same error NETSDK1082. But how is it two different targets if both projects were selected with .NET 5.0?

Comment: I attempted to change the `  "runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\6.0.100-preview.3.21202.5\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"` in the `project.assets.json` to `"runtimeIdentifierGraphPath": "C:\\Program Files\\dotnet\\sdk\\5.0.401\\RuntimeIdentifierGraph.json"` thinking that would work, but I still get the same error

Comment: Is there a particular reason you need to add a reference to the API project in the web assembly project? You should A) opt for a hosted web assembly solution (in which case you will have three projects in the default template - client, server, and shared (client and server have a reference to the shared). You can do that by ticking the ".net hosted" checkbox when creating the project. or B) you should use both independently. Ideally, you should not mix these two models. My bad I didn't spot this earlier.

Comment: I added a reference to the API project in the web assembly project because I am wanting to consume the web api project in the blazor wa using httpclient. I do not want to use option a, if I use option b can I still use the i.e. model class from the web api project into the blazor wa project?

Comment: You don't need to add a reference to the API project. Put the classes in some shared project. Add a reference to that project in both wa and api. That way the api controller methods and wa consumer methods will both be able to use the classes.

Comment: I thought there can only be one project that is being referenced. As in Blazor is referencing the shared project?